# Sentence Structure Question

Tags: sentence-structure

> But his originality as a filmmaker lies most strikingly in **his having
>   successfully adapted film**, originally a Western cultural medium, **to
>   the needs, pace, and structures of West African culture.**

I know all the meanings of the vocabularies in this sentence, but stil I don't understand this sentence because of the structure. Can someone explain the meaning and structure of this sentence by parts?

Comment: Surely you mean words and not vocabularies....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clause headed by *having* represents this clause:

> He has successfully adapted film to X, *where* X = *the needs, pace, and structures of West African culture*.

That is, he has used the medium in ways which reflect West African artistic forms and speak to West African audiences.

This clause is recast with its verb, *has*, in the *-ing* form, *having*, and its subject *he* in the possessive form *his*. In the possessive form the subject thus acts as a determiner and the verb is in effect 'recategorized' as a nominal, something noun-like. In consequence, the entire clause can be employed as the object of the preposition *in*

> His originality . . . lies in Y, *where* Y = *the* having *clause*.

To say that "A lies in B" is a spatial metaphor for expressing the notion that the essence of A is B.

Paraphrase:

> What is original about his work is that he has found ways of making the Western medium work for West African audiences.

Answer (score 0):

But his originality as a filmmaker lies most strikingly in his having successfully adapted film, originally a Western cultural medium, to the needs, pace, and structures of West African culture.

1) ***in his having successfully adapted film to the needs, pace and structures of West African culture.***

Answers the the question: **Where does his originality lie?** *It lies* in [etc.]

Ergo, it is an adverbial phrase even though it is very long. It modifies the verb to lie (from the verb lie, lay, lain). The verb lie in the phrase here is: x lies in y. Which means is found in y.

2) **to** the **needs, pace and structures of West African culture**.

One thing is adapted to another. to the needs etc. is a prepositional embedded in the longer adverbial phrase.